# Store accented letters in C variable

Tags: c

My main language is portuguese so we have some accented words (with á é í ó ú... etc characters) i'm trying to read and store those characters into a variable but it just doesn't work. If i just set it on the code it works, but if i ask the user for input it doesn't. Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    char test, test2; //The same still happens using unsigned char

    test = 'í';

    printf("Character: %c\n", test);

    scanf(" %c", &test2); //The same still happens using fgets in case of a string

    printf("Character: %c\n", test2);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled and executed the code shows:

Character: í

(wait for input, example:) í

character: ¡

if input is 'á' it prints ' '(space), 'é' prints ', ó prints '¢' and ú prints '£'.

I'm new into programming and stackoverflow, so sorry for any mistake i made, every help is appreciated, thank you.

oh, also I'm using Dev-c++ to compile if this make any difference.

Comment: In C, char arrays are made of individual bytes (chars). UTF-8 characters are multiple bytes (chars).

Comment: In the C language the data type `char` holds one byte. The name is misleading: it cannot hold what most people would call a character except in well-controlled situations, for example if the character happens to belong to the ASCII set or if the character is encoded using a legacy 8-bit encoding. That the data type is named `char` instead of `byte` shows that C was invented by speakers of English or Zulu, languages which don't need characters outside the ASCII set.

Comment: Using an array of char (and utf-8) would be my advice to solve the problem, provided the console supports utf-8 okay. Then your language could even be Russian or Chinese. The "%c" formats would need to become "%s".

Answer (score 1):

You need to recognize that a `char` in `C` is a numeric type of size `1 byte`. It actually is not exactly intended to keep the representation of a single language character item. (Sometimes called *code point*).

You do have two options to deal with this situation:

1. Use a character encoding that is single byte. (E.g. the proper
   version of the `iso-8859` family, `iso-8859-1` in your case). This
   will ensure that all characters will fit into a single byte.
2. deal with your input with proper mechanisms for multibyte
   characters. You might look for `char16_t` or `char32_t` types and
   maybe turn to using `wchar_t`  and related library routines